# Xcode snapshot restore fails: "File exists"

Tags: xcode4, restore, snapshot

I need to restore a snapshot which has been created this morning with Xcode 4.3.2.

For some reason I have not commited to git for a few days and made some important changes which I would not like to do again. Yea, I know...

So I run "restore snapshot", select the desired one, then see this error message:

> “libxml2.dylib” couldn’t be copied to “lib” because an item with the
>   same name already exists.

After that, the restore is silently aborted (right after creating a new snapshot). libxml2 is of course the XML library which you can add through Xcode.

In fact, in the file list that appears before the restore, there are 2 entries of libxml2.dylib. But unchecking one, or even two, has no effect.

I also tried removing the existing libxml2.dylib in the project, no change. There is a folder "libs" in the project, but not "lib".

Any idea how to make that error go away or do a restore to a different location, perhaps directly from the snapshot?

Thanks for any help!

m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can restore to a different location through the Organizer.

Start Organizer, click the Projects tab, select your project on the left side, then select the snapshot you need and click on "Export Snapshot" on the bottom left.

Select the folder you would like to restore the snapshot in - there it is!

Good luck to whom this might be useful!